# Is there any option in Paypal seller sandbox account to accept the pending payments?

Tags: paypal

Im working on moodle paypal enrollment feature. I saw that lessons were not getting enrolled to the student even after the successful paypal payemnt. Because the Paypal 'Payment review' setting was set to ON so all the payments are were in pending. I have turned OFF that setting. now I can see the payment complete.

but I do not see an option to accept the 'pending' transaction in sandbox/developer account as seller? Also when seller approves the payment will it trigger IPN simulator and update the payment status to my website?

When payment accepted manually will that call IPN url http://example.com.com/availability/condition/paypal/ipn.php for moodle lessons?

please help me

Answer (score 0):

*The Payment Review feature identifies high-risk transactions and notifies merchants of the review so they can hold shipments until PayPal has evaluated the transaction risk.*

Yes, you will receive one more notification, when the transaction review will be resolved.

With status:

- payment_status: **Completed** *(If the transaction succeeded and the payment was accepted)*
- payment_status: **Reversed** *(If the transaction failed and the payment was rejected)*

You'll find all the notifications here:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/de/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history

Comment: Thanks @Ivan for the reply.  Who is reviewing the payment? Seller has to review the payment and accept right? Where is  the link for seller to review and accept the payment in sanbox?

Comment: Right, the Seller should review the payment. Just open transaction and at the bottom you'll see 2 actions Accept/Deny. For more details: https://www.paypal.com/md/smarthelp/article/what-is-payment-review-and-how-do-i-integrate-it-ts1390

Comment: Thanks again @Ivan. But I am not able to see Accept/Deny options. I can see only "Issue a refund" option.  Im not able to upload screenshot here

Comment: Issue a refund? Have you logged in into business account? or in personal account?

Comment: Business account. I can see the transaction status as pending and I can see Refund or archive option in the transaction listing page. When I click on the transaction, it shows "Issue a Refund"

Comment: I can't help you with this question, my answer was related to notification(s).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you just can't any more. I took this up with PayPal when they redesigned the Transaction Details screen because in the old version, there were indeed Accept/Deny actions as the help page that Ivan has provided a link to.

The support rep's response was "yes, this is an omission which I'll take up with development. For now, you can use the old interface, where you should find those options".

Now, that's probably 2 or more years ago (say 2019) and I haven't seen these Accept/Deny options appear in any transaction details page in the current version, and now there's no option to revert to the old version which did have them.

As a developer, I find PayPal's UI and feature set a set of moving goalposts that it's nigh on impossible to keep up with. I now can't even access my old support tickets to find out what the exact response was. I personally detest the platform.